# Sublime text 3 keymap only runs last command defined

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to create two shortcuts to add these codes on sublime when I hit these keys, but only the second one works, like it overrides the first one.
Does someone have any idea on how to get this working?

I tried this:

```
[{
    "keys": ["ctrl+."],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "<pre><?print_r()?></pre>"
    },

    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+."],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "?><pre><?print_r()?></pre><?"
    },
}]
```

And this:

```
[{
    "keys": ["ctrl+.", "ctrl+alt+."],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "<pre><?print_r()?></pre>",
        "contents": "?><pre><?print_r()?></pre><?"
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each individual key binding needs to be it's own distinct JSON object (i.e. inside of `{}` characters), with `keys` to specify what key triggers it, `command` to specify what to execute and `args` to specify the command arguments.

Assuming it's not a copy/paste error of some sort, the reason your examples don't work the way you want them to is because although they contain valid JSON, they don't contain valid key bindings. So the structure of the file is valid, but the way that Sublime interprets it is different than you intended.

To visualize this, here's your first example with the `[]` characters removed:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+."],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "<pre><?print_r()?></pre>"
    },

    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+."],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "?><pre><?print_r()?></pre><?"
    },
}
```

Now we can see that the very first `{` character is opening the first key binding, but there is no matching `}` character after the `args` of that command; instead we see another set of key binding object keys and the `}` on the last line is the end of the key binding.

In any JSON object (this is not Sublime Text specific), object keys need to be unique; so this is actually a single JSON object with each key duplicated. Sublime's reaction to this is to ignore the first three keys in favor of the second three.

This ends you up with a single key binding instead of two of them, and it's the second one, so <kbd>ctrl+alt+.</kbd> works, but <kbd>ctrl+.</kbd> doesn't because it was ignored.

In your second example, the duplicate object key is in the `args` key of the key binding; that means that when the key binding triggers, the `insert_snippet` command will execute, but the argument that it gets will be the contents of that second key.

In this case this binding works, but what you (perhaps inadvertently) did was define a key binding that requires you to press two keys in sequence in order to trigger it. That is, you would need to press <kbd>ctrl+.</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl+alt+.</kbd> in order for the key binding to trigger.

I think based on your examples you intended to have two distinct key bindings that each insert something different, and the first example is closest to that; you just need to insert `},` after the first `args` and a `{` before the second `keys`:

```json
[
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+."],
        "command": "insert_snippet",
        "args": {
            "contents": "<pre><?print_r()?></pre>"
        },
    },

    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+alt+."],
        "command": "insert_snippet",
        "args": {
            "contents": "?><pre><?print_r()?></pre><?"
        },
    },
]
```

Here I've reformatted your second example with the additional fix in place to help clarify that it's the `{}` that are defining the individual key bindings, the `[]` characters are for wrapping the list of bindings in the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's so well explained!